# path constant works locally, doesn't on dev

Tags: focus-lab-master-config

Using Focus Lab Master Config, I've defined these constants for my dev environment:

```
define('ENV', 'dev');
define('ENV_FULL', 'Development');
define('ENV_DEBUG', TRUE);
define('ENV_BASE_PATH', '/home/public_html/dev/');
define('ENV_BASE_URL', 'mywebsite.com');
```

In config.master.php I have this line:

```
$env_config['tmpl_file_basepath']        = ENV_BASE_PATH . 'templates/';
```

Now when I check my Global Template Preferences in the CP, I get this:

> ENV_BASE_PATHtemplates/

As a test, when I put ENV, ENV_FULL or ENV_DEBUG in the $env_config line in stead, it prints correctly. On my local install there's no issue at all. Did I miss another setting needed to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the `ENV_BASE_PATH` constant defined for *each* environment? It sounds like you only set it up under one.

The goal of this file (`config.env.php`) is to set constants *per* environment so you would want it to look something like the following:

```
if ( ! defined('ENV'))
{
    switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
        case 'domain.com' :
            define('ENV', 'prod');
            define('ENV_FULL', 'Production');
            define('ENV_DEBUG', FALSE);
            define('ENV_BASE_PATH', '/home/public_html/dev/');
            define('ENV_BASE_URL', 'mywebsite.com');
        break;

        case 'dev.domain.com' :
            define('ENV', 'dev');
            define('ENV_FULL', 'Development');
            define('ENV_DEBUG', TRUE);
            define('ENV_BASE_PATH', '/home/public_html/dev/');
            define('ENV_BASE_URL', 'mywebsite.com');
        break;

        default :
            define('ENV', 'local');
            define('ENV_FULL', 'Local');
            define('ENV_DEBUG', TRUE);
            define('ENV_BASE_PATH', '/home/public_html/dev/');
            define('ENV_BASE_URL', 'mywebsite.com');
        break;
    }
}
```

You would obviously want to change the paths per environment, but that's the gist.

**Question though:** Why are you setting constants here rather than just letting [the auto-created paths](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config/blob/master/config/config.master.php#L94) in `config.master.php` do their thing? What's the goal at hand?

Comment: Good point. I'm not that familiar with php and setting up my multi env MSM sites took a bit of trial and error. When it eventually all worked I left it alone. The solution you suggested worked, I had an environment that was missing the constants. I did manage to remove them all from config.env.php. Thanks!